# Spring security blocks access to styles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, security

I encountered a problem that at some point some of the styles in my spring project stopped working. I use bootstrap styles and styles written by me personally in the css file.
After starting the program for some reason only 1 part of them is displayed. When viewing "Network" in Google developer tools, I found that the styles file is redirected to http://localhost:8080/login for some reason, although I have access to the styles file.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGorT.png)

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/reg", "/registration/**", "/static/**", "/static/images/**", "/static/styles/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .failureUrl("/login_error")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/pc")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/"));

        return http.build();
    }
```

After discovering this, I decided to comment out the spring security dependency in pom.xml and also commented out all classes that use it.
After that, the styles started working and everything continued to work when spring security was uncommented. However, when I restarted my computer and started the project, I encountered the same problem again.
What could this be related to and how can it be resolved?
I need your help very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Spring Security to ignore resources under src/main/resources/static. You can do so by adding `http.authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests. .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll())`  to your security config and remove all the `"/static/...` references from your existing configuration.